# Do electricity distribution companies charge apparent power (VA) or effective power (W)

Tags: power, power-consumption

If there is a load connected to a power outlet during one hour, where average apparent power is 1000VA and average effective power is 800W, what will be charged by the eletricity distribution company? The VA power (apparent) or the W power (effective)?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Yes, a user replied that what is charged is V x A x PF, that is, the real power in Watts

Comment: Larger industrial customers may be charged “power factor penalty” charges if they maintain a bad power factor.